# PHP move files with specific name

Tags: php, file

I have 100.000+ files with name **RMA_(NUMBER)*(DATE)*(TIME).jpg** like **RMA_12345_2015_10_12_17_00_35.jpg**

How I can move this file like **RMA_35200_*.jpg**?

Comment: http://php.net/glob http://php.net/foreach

Comment: `exec('mv /path/to/files/RMA_35200_*.jpg /destination/dir');`

Comment: another option would be scandir and fnmatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command:

```
$ mv RMA_35200_*.jpg new_path
```

or use php for that, example:

```
<?php

$fromPath = __DIR__ . '/from';
$toPath = __DIR__ . '/to';

$files = glob("{$fromPath}/RMA_35200_*.jpg");

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileName = basename($file);
    rename($file, "{$toPath}/{$fileName}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()`to find those files and `rename()` to move them

```
function moveFiles($source, $target) {
  // add missing "/" after target
  if(substr($target,-1) != '/') $target .= '/';

  $files = glob($source);
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    $destination = $target . $info['filename'];
    rename($file, $destination);
  }
}

moveFiles('/where/my/files/are/RMA_35200_*.jpg', '/where/they/should/be/';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to agree with the other comments, "Use glob()to find those files and rename() to move them", etc.

But, there's one thing I would add, a preg_match for the file name. PERL regular expression matching the file name. I think that's what you may be missing from these answers.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (preg_match('/RMA_[0-9\-_]+.jpg/i', $file) {
        ...more code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: regex is not needed as `glob()`support wildcards like "RMA_35200_*.jpg"